# High io usage by jbd2/sda2-8

Tags: linux, io

I am experiencing high io usage by jbd while running my python test utility which constantly talks to sqlitedb which results in high io wait time. How should I resolve the issue?

It consumes 99% of IO even while it's not writing to disk!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caused by journalling block device which takes high amount of I/O usage whenever I run my modules, disabling it using tune2fs utility solved the problem.

Comment: What was the exact procedure to disable it (or do you have a link with more info)? I ask because it would be helpful for me and possibly others too :P

Answer (score 0):

Alternative could be to increase time for flushing to disk by adding `commit=nrsec` to `/etc/fstab` where `nrsec` should be higher than default 5 seconds.